# Laravel select field cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to store a form into my database but this is the error i get:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'rent_product' cannot be null
```

Why is this?

I'm trying to do this in an array because i have an option to show more select fields (to add more products to rent).

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
 <label for="sel1">Selecteer product:</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="height: 40px;">
     @foreach ($pr as $prr)
      <option name="product_name[]" value="{{$prr->product_name}}">{{$prr->product_name}}</option>
     @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```

Function:

```
public function create_order($id) {

    $customer = Customer::find($id);

    $customer->rent_product = Request::get('product_name');
    $customer->rent_product_count = Request::get('product_count');
    $customer->update();


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the complete form code along with the customer and product model with schema. The error is because your input `product_name` is empty. Also `$customer->update();` should be `$customer->update();`. The select values should probably be product id instead of the name.

Comment: Typo in the comment above, i meant it should be `$customer->save();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You should use name attribute in the select tag. code below

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
 <label for="sel1">Selecteer product:</label>
   <select name="product_name" class="form-control" id="sel1" style="height: 40px;">
     @foreach ($pr as $prr)
      <option value="{{$prr->product_name}}">{{$prr->product_name}}</option>
     @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```

and then

```
$customer = Customer::find($id);
$customer->rent_product = Request::get('product_name');
$customer->rent_product_count = Request::get('product_count');
$customer->save();
```

Comment: This worked! But, how do i pass this trough an array? I have an option to create a new selectbox to add multiple products.

Comment: make name attribute as array like name = "product_name[ ]".           $customer = Customer::find($id);
$customer->insert(Input::all());     can try it

Answer (score 0):

Change `$customer->update();` to `$customer->save();`. The `update` method expects you to pass the attributes array to update. So you're making an update without any values.

```
$customer = Customer::find($id);
$customer->rent_product = Request::get('product_name');
$customer->rent_product_count = Request::get('product_count');
$customer->save();

// This is what you need to do if you want to use `update`

$customer->update([
    'rent_product' => Request::get('product_name'),
    'rent_product_count' => Request::get('product_count')
]);

// Or you can do this to update in a single query

Customer::where('id', $id)->update([
    'rent_product' => Request::get('product_name'),
    'rent_product_count' => Request::get('product_count')
]);
```

Answer (score -2):

The error states that your model does not have a column with the name `rent_product`. Check your `Customer` migrations if you have set this column.

Something like this:

```
// file: database/migrations/20170000_create_customers_table.php

Schema::create("customers", function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('rent_product');
    $table->integer('rent_product_count');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`$customer->rent_product` would be `rent_product` in your customers table. (in the database)

Also check if you have migrated your tables with `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: No the error states `Column 'rent_product' cannot be null`. Which  means he's assigning null to a column which needs a value.

Comment: Oopsi, misinterpreted this stuff. Sorry guys.

Comment: A little bit more detail on his problem would definitely make it more clear, what he wants.